Problem when Installing Mixamo addon on Blender. Please help me, I cant do what the video tutorial I shared shows, Ive tried so much things
IM HAVING TROUBLES WHEN INSTALLING THE MIXAMO ADDON FOR BLENDER.
and this is the video tutorial https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=B_A4cI6JZyA should work fine but does not wor for me. thanks.

Instead of asking the same question several times, try to improve the original question by using the edit button.

Abobe has not updated the addon for for Blender 4+.
Download it from here. https://gitlab.com/x190/mixamo_blender4

